# SharedSizeGroup weird jumping/flickering when SharedSizeGroup is inside ItemsControl generated items

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Problem (happens on switching list bound to ItemsSource - when rows with SharedSizeGroup disappear for a moment):

[image: very weird jumping]

So I have a `Grid` with `IsSharedSizeScope="True"`. The control that I'm building is a calendar/scheduler control.

I have a `TimeRuler` control that I need to align to the headers (orange rectangle in the screenshot below). I use SharedSizeGroup for that. The problem is `SharedSizeGroup` is inside generated items of `ItemsControl` and that is causing some weird delay as you can see in the gif.

Is there anyway to make it re-render **after** ItemsContainerGenerator renders the first item or finishes loading?

Snippet that is causing the problem:

```xml
<!--  to even time ruler out  -->
<Grid
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    Margin="0,-1,0,0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!-- both SuperHeader and LocationHeader are rendered later and this is causing this weird flickering/jumping -->
        <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="SuperHeader" />
        <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="LocationHeader" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Visual tree more or less:

[image: visualtree]

This can be solved by making those heights fixed and not using SharedSizeGroup but it won't be that flexible anymore...

Or making sure that ItemsControl is never empty e.g. using ObservableCollection, adding new items and removing old items after. This way RowDefinition with SharedSizeGroup is always present in the visual tree...

Really annoying... I don't think it's even possible to use SharedSizeGroup in such situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing collection bound to `ItemsSource` was never as fast as I wanted it to be. Neither was clearing and adding items. It was causing everything to re-render and it was painfully slow.

Because I  couldn't find a better solution I just add(populate) day items once and then just replace them using `items[i]` syntax. This way UI won't have to be re-rendered completely each time you want to display a different range of dates.